# How to put math symbols (e.g. R^n) into Java String?

Tags: java, math, javafx, unicode

I would like to display the R^n math symbol in a javafx Label. How could I do this? I found the unicode number for a real number - U+211x (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_operators_and_symbols_in_Unicode#Letterlike_Symbols_block), but inserting \u+211x into the Label string like below gives an 'invalid unicode' error

```
Label dim_label = new Label("n ( \u+212x ^n):");
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct symbol is `\u211D`, the `x` in Wikipedia is just a placeholder and the `+` should not go to the string.

The exponent `n` is [`SUPERSCRIPT LATIN SMALL LETTER N`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/207f/index.htm)  and can be represented with `\u207F`.

So all in all:

```
Label dim_label = new Label("n ( \u211D\u207F):");
```

[**Live demo:**](https://ideone.com/qs8VMc).

> ```
> n ( ℝⁿ):
> ```